# Relationship between line, circle, helix

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to wrap my head around the relationship between the distance traveled by a point on a line going up and down, mapping that to the circumference of a circle, and then mapping that to either the arc length of a sine wave or a helix. The distance traveled for each is different but I tried to see if there was a constant that these distances scaled by, and I couldn't find one.
Is there one? Or am I missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arc length of a helix.

Consider a paper towel roll.  The seam of the towel roll is a helix.  and we can cut the roll along the seam and un-roll it, and form a parallelogram.  The length of the helix equals the length of the side of the parallelogram.

[image]

This length will be governed by the Pythagorean theorem.

$l = \sqrt{h^2 + 2\pi r n}$ where $n$ is the number of times the helix wraps around the cylinder.

We do not have a linear relationship here, so there will not be a "scaling factor."

Comment: That helped, thank you very much. I was picturing the point moving like sin wave, your diagram made me realize it's a triangle wave. Now I understand. Onward!